# How to list database names available in derby server?

Tags: derby

Suppose I have connected to the the derby server. I need to know which datagbases are available for me to connect to. Is there a command to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such command. Derby does not maintain an overall registry or catalog of all known databases.

Each database is independent, and can be opened by providing the correct JDBC Connection URL. The JDBC Connection URL specifies the location of the database folder on the server's disk, either as an absolute path name, or relative to the Derby Network Server's "home" directory.

If you have physical access to the server machine, you can perform a filesystem search and look for Derby database folders.

Otherwise, it is the responsibility of the application to keep track of which databases it is using and where they are located.

For more information about the JDBC Connection URL, look here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html

And for more information about controlling the Derby Network Server's home directory, look here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefproper32066.html

Comment: Theoretically there is the DatabaseMetaData.getCatalogs() but it gives me back an empty ResultSet.